# Cannot install android sdk packages

Tags: java, android, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to update my packages in the android sdk. When I run:

```
sudo android sdk
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:65)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2543)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2567)
```

Java version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Javac version

```
javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20
```

This is on an ubuntu 12.04 system. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using http instead of https

Comment: Forcing http worked! Post it as an answer so that I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings, check `Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...`